# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

*NOTE - This code is from a third party extension. I had no part of it's creation and several years ago when used it was the only extension available at the time. So while I appreciate your opinions, I do hope all comments can be just for suggestions on a resolution. Thanks!

We have many sites running a Google Maps component for a CMS that allows for clients to add markers and outlines (polygons) to their Google Maps.

This has been working for years. To note, it uses Google Maps JS API 2, which has been discontinued rather than API 3. However, Google has noted API 2 will still work well into 2013 so that is not the issue. However, they must have changed something because as of the other day, on all our sites though the Maps appear the markers and polygons do not. They are on different servers.

Before there was no errors but now in Chrome it says:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" for line 1669 in a JS File. You can see the file in the following Gist:

https://gist.github.com/2238148

As you can see there is no missing ")" and the code has work unmodified for years on nearly 100 sites, so assume something on Google's end must have changed. But is there something we can adjust to this code to help counter there change? -Update on March 25th when all of this broke Google made an update to their Google Maps API 2.

Searched the web and here is an example site using the same component with the same error: http://goo.gl/GMgOs

This issue appears to be near:

```
// extract current digraph from overlay function
    var digraph = GMap.addOverlay.toString().replace(/\s/g,'').replace(/.push\([^{]+\);a.initialize\([^{]+\);a.redraw\([^{]+\).+$/,'').replace(/^.+\./,'');
    // add multiple overlays at once (api hack to improve loading speed)
    GMap2.prototype.addOverlays = function(a) {
        var b = eval('this.' + digraph);
        var i = a.length;
        while (i--) {
            b.push(a[i]);
            a[i].initialize(this);
            a[i].redraw(true);
        }
    }
```

If that code needs to be alterted could someone post the modified version on a gist or pastie?

Another Update - That code in the pre above I commented out since it supposively is not needed by was a hack to speed things up. Still gets an error however noted in the comments. I did notice however here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GMap2.Methods.Overlays that it calls the code, "addOverlay" rather than "addOverlays" so wondering if maybe the s was taken off in the most recent API Google update. Removing the s in all three locations just shoots out a new error which repeats [object] many times.

Comment: I would suggest to JSLint it because Aptana shows many errors when JSLint validation is active. This way you will find your problem for sure.

Comment: @helly0d: The SyntaxError seems to happen in an eval. I guess JSLint can't find that, it would only say "don't use eval" :-)

Comment: @Bergi First of all it actually says "eval is evil", second point, even so you should JSLint it because it has a lot of errors, and finally but not least, try to see the code sent for eval and debug it, if it has bugs either make a fixing tool for unfinished JS code or convince Google to JSLint their code :p. So in the end there is nothing you can do but report a bug if you are sure it is not your code's fault. Good luck.

Comment: @helly0d Just a note in case not clear in the post, the code linked is not google's code. It's a third party extension by a third party developer who no longer maintains it. Google created the Google Maps API but they have no part of the third party code linked above. So while it would have been nice had that developer linted their code several years ago when they created it, they did not. So this StackOverflow, is simply to resolve the current issue in it's current form. But thank you.

Comment: RE: `addOverlay` vs `addOverlays`. The API has always only ever supported the `addOverlay` method. The code snippet you've pasted is a hack to create the plural `addOverlays` version (an awful and unnecessary hack).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Dave! Another commenter was able to provide a fix to allow addOverlays to work. Before next year all sites will be using My Maps, so thankfully we now have time to upgrade everyone properly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is an abomination, in fact I've not seen a worse add-on in five years of working with and helping users of Version 2. It overwrites GMap (part of the Version 2 API to provide compatibility with Version 1) with no redeclaration. The error you're getting is a direct result of a hack to minified code: this was bound to fail at some point and should never have been implemented.

The best thing you can do is to remove the `var digraph` line and then redefine the new method `GMap2.prototype.addOverlays` which follows it. That will allow the code to use the API's `addOverlay()` function and should eliminate the problem.

```
GMap2.prototype.addOverlays = function(a) {
        var i = a.length;
        while (i--) {
             this.addOverlay(a[i]);
        }
```

It appears that `addOverlays()` takes an array of overlays. The existing method attempts to add them directly to the *internal* array of overlays, which has moved. The suggested method simply uses GMap2's own `addOverlay()` method to add each member of the array of objects. Thus we use an exposed method and don't try and hijack the minified code of the API — if we did that again, it would almost certainly break again.

---

`GMarker.prototype.openInfoWindowFX` and `GMarker.prototype.updateInfoWindow` are additions to GMarker and unlikely to cause problems (especially if they currently work), although even they use properties of GMarker -- which isn't really recommnded.

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks as noted this extension was not developed by us, so any comments about how good or bad it is unfortunately do not help so hopefully you an others can help with the actual issue. Unfortunately, for the CMS used it was the only extension available that met the specific needs of the client at the time, a hard coded solution was not practical at the time. All new sites simply use Google My Maps embed now. This request is simply to fix several 100 existing sites hopefully by updating this one file. Rather than spending weeks replacing with My Maps version.

Comment: For your suggestion, the code exercept in the original post, the var digraph and the gmap2 section, we tried commenting out, but still errored out and the poylgons and markers still did not appear. Any other thoughts?

Comment: To add, when commenting out that code the resulting error is: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Se> has no method 'addOverlays' and it references the error at: line 559: GMap.addOverlays(markers); GMap.addOverlays(polygons); GMap.addOverlays(polylines);   (and those are the actions that aren't working on the map. That is the map always shows up fine, its just the markers and polylines/polygons that don't show up. Let me know if you have any other ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Andrew, andrew, andrew....along with 50 points you totally get a Sam Adams if you ever visit Boston. Works! You rock! Hopefully this time next year everyone will be migrated to Google My Maps and never have to look at this code again. Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the `GMap.addOverlay` function definition has been changed and your RegExp hacking at its source code no longer works.

```
alert(GMap.addOverlay.toString())
```

and

```
alert(digraph)
```

To see what the new function is and what your regexes are doing to it.

Why exactly do you need to in-place modify their code, anyways? Why didn't you just copy the function definition you wanted, make the changes, and then use that version? (Without needing an `eval`, either.)

Comment: We are willing to make any changes that are provided via this site, that will not break the functionality of the CMS. As a reminder this is a component developed by a third party that is no longer developed.  We can change anything in the component code as long as when the client enters in new markers/polygons, settings, they will show up properly. We can change, "GMap.addOverlays(markers);" to "alert(GMap.addOverlays(markers));" as well as for Polygon and Polygons and post for the results here. We can add "alert(digraph)" as well. Should we add that right after line 1669?

Comment: Replaced the three lines with alert( versions, but nothing changed. No alter popups that is. Could you let me know what exactly should be changed to get the information you need for further diagnosis? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just tried adding alert(digraph); and that did show an alter when reloading the page. It said, "Xv(a));v(this,"addoverlay",a)}"

Comment: Since alert on the gmap doesnt appear to work, I added, alert(markers); alert(polygons); alert(polylines); right before the lines about addoverlay and I got three alerts: 1) [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]  2) [object Object],[object Object]  3) [object Object]   Does that mean anything?

Comment: @heavymark *"Xv(a));v(this,"addoverlay",a)}"* -- there are two ) in the first expression as well as an extra } at the end. This will fail. It's **highly** likely that the new v2.s (25 March) has broken this; but again, trying to extract from minified code is always risky and *never* recommended.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks Adam. I don't believe the JS file linked in the post is minified. That excerpt you quoted is just the output of trying an alert another user suggested. So imagine just Chrome removes formatting when doing alerts. And yeah 100s of site google maps all broke at the same time on that day so there is no doubt it was caused by there changes. That's not to say that Google made a mistake. That is most likely this third party coded as it says in its own comments used a hack, and Google simply changed something that broke that hack. But still at a lost on how to resolve it.

Comment: Sorry, today was a busy day. I meant to alert the code so you could debug what the heck it's doing and then try to fix it. If this isn't even your group's code and is no longer maintained, I would completely scrap the regex & eval approach and just redo the method (if that's even necessary) totally inline in the source so you don't get surprises like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted relies on internal implementation details for `GMap2.prototype.addOverlay` which are free to change at any time.

It would be better to rely only on the external interface for `GMap2`. You can implement an `addOverlays` method as such:

```
GMap2.prototype.addOverlays = function(overlays) {
  for (var i = 0, I = overlays.length; i < I; ++i) {
    this.addOverlay(overlays[i]);
  }
};
```

Can you replace the code snippet from your post with this and see if it works?

Comment: Hey Dave, just saw this which looks very similar to the other commenters solution which worked. Didn't try this one but since it looks similiar imagine it would work as well. Since his was posted 4 hours before this it appears and works awarding him the points, but to other people reading this, this solution may be more efficient. Thank you again Dave!

Answer (score 0):

That code is ugly. You do `GMap.addOverlay.toString()`, replace something with regular expressions and execute it then with eval.

Why do you need to replace something in a function's code? What is the code of `GMap.addOverlay`? If you can answer these questions, you should be able to see why your regexp doesn't work any more and returns invalid code.

Comment: Yes, the code probably isn't the best. It's an free third party component developed years ago. Unfortunately, it's the only available extension for this particular CMS that does our particular needs. To note, the code has always worked on all nearly 100 sites, until the other day when they stopped working right. We have changed no code, so something in the Google Maps API must have changed. Most likely the extension relied on a hack of some sort that Google changed. While I appreciate your questions about the code, I'm unable to answer any of them. Simply hopeing for the best resolution.

Comment: Also since as noted its an extension to a CMS, so the contents of "addoverlay" are dynamic. That is in the CMS the user has a UI that allows them to add markers or polygons (outlines). On all separate 100+ sites its always worked until the other day when all of the sudden the markers/polygons disappeared off the maps and that error appeared in Chrome Console.